# ggplot2 scale_x_discrete causes my x axis to dissapear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(row = c("(BSO,0)", "(BSO,1)", "(BSO,2)", "(BSO,3)", 
"(BSO,4)", "(BSO,5)", "(BSO,6)", "(CAR,0)", "(CAR,1)", "(CAR,2)", 
"(CAR,3)", "(CAR,4)", "(GMA,0)", "(GMA,1)", "(GMA,2)", "(GMA,3)", 
"(GMA,4)", "(GRA,0)", "(GRA,1)", "(GRA,2)", "(GRA,3)", "(GRS,7)", 
"(MAI,0)", "(MAI,1)", "(MAI,3)", "(MAI,5)", "(MAI,6)", "(MAI,7)", 
"(MAI,8)", "(ONI,0)", "(ONI,1)", "(ONI,4)", "(ONI,41)", "(ONI,45)", 
"(ONI,48)", "(ONI,49)", "(POT,0)", "(POT,1)", "(POT,2)", "(POT,3)", 
"(POT,5)", "(POT,6)", "(POT,8)", "(POT,9)", "(SBA,3)", "(SBA,5)", 
"(SBA,7)", "(SBA,8)", "(SBA,9)", "(SBT,0)", "(SBT,1)", "(SBT,2)", 
"(SBT,11)", "(SBT,14)", "(SBT,19)", "(SBT,32)", "(SBT,39)", "(SCR,1)", 
"(SCR,2)", "(SCR,3)", "(SWH,5)", "(SWH,7)", "(SWH,8)", "(SWH,9)", 
"(TLP,0)", "(TLP,6)", "(TLP,12)", "(TLP,45)", "(TLP,48)", "(TLP,49)", 
"(VEG,1)", "(VEG,2)", "(VEG,8)", "(WBA,8)", "(WCR,0)", "(WCR,1)", 
"(WWH,2)", "(WWH,3)", "(WWH,5)", "(WWH,7)", "(WWH,8)", "(WWH,9)", 
"(WWH,29)"), numofpics = c(1484, 1299, 1923, 3494, 2259, 934, 
1962, 209, 2218, 63, 16, 2178, 69, 165, 491, 147, 217, 114, 988, 
4518, 969, 26, 45, 479, 1102, 103, 69, 557, 144, 514, 1398, 59, 
494, 217, 610, 113, 872, 779, 152, 364, 20, 774, 995, 631, 23, 
145, 34, 66, 107, 448, 307, 17, 68, 757, 51, 47, 3787, 318, 578, 
431, 214, 167, 20, 24, 261, 378, 154, 58, 20, 70, 925, 22, 42, 
21, 35, 142, 703, 750, 76, 643, 278, 273, 27), numofparcels = c(49, 
40, 63, 94, 68, 32, 61, 8, 32, 2, 1, 30, 2, 7, 19, 6, 10, 5, 
27, 52, 27, 1, 2, 20, 25, 4, 3, 23, 5, 19, 25, 2, 17, 7, 20, 
5, 29, 27, 4, 11, 1, 20, 25, 21, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 16, 10, 1, 2, 
27, 1, 1, 34, 12, 15, 16, 8, 6, 1, 1, 10, 9, 6, 2, 1, 3, 12, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 16, 19, 3, 19, 8, 10, 1), crop = c("BSO", "BSO", 
"BSO", "BSO", "BSO", "BSO", "BSO", "CAR", "CAR", "CAR", "CAR", 
"CAR", "GMA", "GMA", "GMA", "GMA", "GMA", "GRA", "GRA", "GRA", 
"GRA", "GRS", "MAI", "MAI", "MAI", "MAI", "MAI", "MAI", "MAI", 
"ONI", "ONI", "ONI", "ONI", "ONI", "ONI", "ONI", "POT", "POT", 
"POT", "POT", "POT", "POT", "POT", "POT", "SBA", "SBA", "SBA", 
"SBA", "SBA", "SBT", "SBT", "SBT", "SBT", "SBT", "SBT", "SBT", 
"SBT", "SCR", "SCR", "SCR", "SWH", "SWH", "SWH", "SWH", "TLP", 
"TLP", "TLP", "TLP", "TLP", "TLP", "VEG", "VEG", "VEG", "WBA", 
"WCR", "WCR", "WWH", "WWH", "WWH", "WWH", "WWH", "WWH", "WWH"
), bbch = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
0L, 1L, 4L, 41L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 19L, 32L, 39L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 29L)), .Names = c("row", 
"numofpics", "numofparcels", "crop", "bbch"), row.names = c(NA, 
83L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish to graph with `ggplot` like so:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=row, y=numofpics, fill = crop)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(df$crop), labels = unique(df$crop))
```

in order to produce a graph like this:

[image]

with the only exception that the legend labels get displayed on the X axis. For the life of me, I don't get why they instead disappear.

Although my data is not numeric/continuous, I've tried converting to factor:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(row), y=numofpics, fill = factor(crop))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(df$crop), labels = unique(df$crop))
```

which produced the same result.

And I've tried this solution from another thread:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(row), y=numofpics, fill = factor(crop))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(df$crop))
```

which did this:

[image]

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You're setting `aes(x=row, ...`, meaning the x-axis labels and breaks will come from the `row` column, but then in `scale_x_discrete` you're setting `breaks=unique(df$crop)`. Since `row` has different values than `crop` (i.e., the break values you've set don't exist in `row`), the axis labels disappear. If you want the x-axis labels to be the values of `crop`, then 
 set `aes(x=crop, ...` (and you can also remove the call to `scale_x_discrete`).

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, but No, this is not what I want to do. I want to have the graph as presented, but with the labels from `crop` placed under the respectively same colored clusters of bars. I'm sure this is possible, but I'm just not sure of the correct syntax.

Comment: Looking at your data, probably `scale_x_discrete(labels = df$crop)` will work here. In general, the key is to make sure the ordering of the `labels` vector corresponds exactly to the ordering of the original x-axis labels.

Comment: Doing `scale_x_discrete(labels = df$crop)` produces the result I am trying to escape in the first place with this whole `scale_x_discrete` business - a cluttered, messy x axis. The ordering of the `labels` vector can't exactly correspond to the original X axis data, as there are 83 rows, which are grouped in 17 categories. I wish to have the 83 rows displayed like in the graph I've uploaded, but labelled based on the 17 categories they belong to. Do you mean to tell me this is impossible with `ggplot` and `scale_x_discrete`???

Comment: It wasn't initially clear from your question, but it looks like what you want is a single `crop` label that spans all of the `row` values that go with each `crop`. One way to do this is with facetting. See my answer for details and let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you described, it looks like you might want something like one of these, but please let me know if this isn't what you had in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=str_extract(row, "[0-9]+"), y=numofpics, fill = crop)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_grid(. ~ crop, scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle=-90),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.8)))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(bbch), y=numofpics, fill = crop)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=bbch), vjust=-0.25, size=3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ crop, scales="free_x", space="free_x", switch="x") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle=-90),
        strip.placement="outside", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.8)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @eipi10, this is almost the desired outcome. For some reason though your solution squishes some of the crop bins, notably ONI, SBT and TLP. This becomes really obvious when you insert the label for each column via `+geom_text(aes(label=bbch), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)` . Any idea as to why this data squish might be occurring?

Comment: Sorry, that was an error on my part. I didn't account for `row` > 9 in my code and was therefore extracting only the first digit of each row number. The result was multiple bars overplotted in the same place (which was revealed when you ran `geom_text` and saw multiple `bbch` values at the same x-axis location).  Changing from `"[0-9]"` to `"[0-9]+"` takes care of that. In the second graph, I've added your `geom_text` line for illustration and also switched to using `factor(bbch)` for the `x` aesthetic.

Comment: aaaa sneaky regex, I have to learn how to use this once and for all. in any case - you, Sir, are a true master!